# MySQL 8.0 syntax error on Mac OS Mojave 10.14.3

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to change the password for mysql using commands I've seen work for many other people. Currently, I am facing a brick wall of a syntax error here:

```
UPDATE user SET authentication_String = PASSWORD('elephant7') WHERE user='root';
```

The syntax error is within this area: '('`elephant7`') WHERE `user='root';'`

Anything would help.

Comment: It will make it easier for others to answer your question if you properly format your SQL code and include the actual error message you are receiving.

Comment: `\`user\`` should be wrapped with back-ticks . https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html

Comment: I think @Alex has the correct answer. It appears `user` is a reserved word. That's probably why I don't use it as a field name. Kind of like `first`. Some people back-tick everything just to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 2):

> PASSWORD(str)
>
> This function was removed in MySQL 8.0.11.

from [official docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password)